# Simplifying expressions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

Is it mathematically valid  to simplify the expression
$$\left ( \bar \Psi \right)^2
\left(1, \ -1\right)$$
to 1 if
$$\Psi =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(x) & 0 \\ 0 & i \sin(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$
(where $\bar \Psi$ is the complex conjugate of $\Psi$)?
Since
\begin{align}
\left( \bar \Psi \right)^2 \left(1,\ -1\right)
&= \bar \Psi \bar \Psi \left(1,\ -1\right)
&= \bar \Psi \Psi \\
&= 1
\end{align}

Comment: Use mathjax. Please do not post images of math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\bar\Psi =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(x) & 0 \\ 0 & -i \sin(x)
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then,
$$
\bar\Psi\bar\Psi=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos^2(x) & 0 \\ 0 & -\sin^2(x)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This yields
$$
\bar\Psi\bar\Psi\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos^2(x) & 0 \\ 0 & -\sin^2(x)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2(x) \\ \sin^2(x)\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Oops! I meant the second term to be a row vector! And in that case, it would be simplified to one (right?), sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Matrix001 Please edit your question to fix your error that you mentioned, otherwise the question isn't really answerable until we know what you are asking.